# How to hide each Div from a class based on where a column is empty or not empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, class

Is this valid in JQuery?

```
$('.Class').(this).hide()
```

if not whats the work around for this, i want to do something like this.

```
echo '
<Div>
<img src="'.$row['image1'].'">
</Div>
'

if (!empty($row['image1'])){
echo   '<script>
        $('.Class').(this).hide()
    </script>';
}
```

This should hide only images that who's scr returned no value.

Comment: Use `$('.Class').hide()`, Assuming you want to hide elements with class `Class`

Comment: you can use $('img src=""').hide() to hide all images that contains empty src.

Comment: @Suleman The attribute selector is written as `[src=""]`

Comment: @Satpal that will hide the entire class.

Comment: Why not echo <img src="' . $row ['image1'] . '" ' .($row ['image1'] ? '' : ' style="display:none"') . '>

Comment: why not just not `echo` it in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="class1">
  <div id="div1" class="class2"><img src="img_src1" /></div>
  <div id="div2" class="class2"><img src="img_src2" /></div>
  <div id="div3" class="class2"><img src="img_src3" /></div>
  <div id="div4" class="class2"><img src="" /></div>
  <div id="div5" class="class2"><img src="" /></div>
</div>

<script>
  // you can call
  // This will hide div4 and div5
  $('.class1 img[src=""]').parent().hide();

  // This will do the same
  $('.class2 img[src=""]').parent().hide();

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do with PHP direcly... no?
like:

```
if (!empty($row['image1'])){
   echo '<Div><img src="'.$row['image1'].'"></Div>'
}
```

if $row['image1'] is not empty echo the image.
If you want to show however

```
if (!empty($row['image1'])){
   echo '<Div><img src="'.$row['image1'].'"></Div>';
}else{
    echo '<Div><img style="display:none" src="'.$row['image1'].'"></Div>'
}
```

no?

Comment: or just do an if in the `<img>` for the `style attribute`

Comment: sure... if you want to insert a logic inside the echo yes, you can.

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

> $('img[src=""]').hide()

Answer (score 0):

try that instead

```
$('.Class').hide()
```

Comment: There's a difference between $(this) and $('.Class'). $(this) on that which was selected in a class, not the whole class.

Answer (score 0):

se this code

```
$('.Class').hide()
```

If u want animation then u can use

```
$( ".Class" ).hide( "slow" );
```

or

```
$( ".Class" ).hide( 2000 );
```

value in milliseconds

Use this api documentation.. http://api.jquery.com/hide/
Enjoy....

Comment: You are hiding all divs in that class.